# How to change a project's name in Eclipse

Tags: android

How can I change a project's name in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Soong is a build system specifically for Android Platform development, and not Android app development, even though the Android Platform can contain regular Android apps built for the system image. That means Soong is not supported to use outside of Android Platform builds.

Your best bet here is to import/copy DeskClock's source code into Android Studio and write your own `build.gradle` files manually.

Comment: So you mean I should use the Gradle build system and find out which dependencies I need to implement into `build.gradle` on my own, right?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Isn't there a faster way to know which dependencies etc. I need for a certain project? It would be very unpractical if everybody who imports the project needs to go trough the project's classes for hours and hours just to know which dependencies etc. to add into `build.gradle`

Comment: as far as I know, no. If the app maintainers didn't provide the Gradle build files, you'd have to write them yourself.

Comment: You can use that as a guide to create your build.gradle file, yes. There is not automated converter to Gradle, AFAIK.